# "media: inaccessible or not found" error when attempting to control device volume via ADB

Tags: adb, volume-control

I'm trying to [change volume on my device via ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055947/adb-command-to-set-volume).

When for instance running

```
adb shell media volume --stream 15 --set 0
```

...this error is returned ([regarding the volume streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652747/what-is-the-difference-between-audiomanagers-stream-types-at-low-level)):

```
/system/bin/sh: media: inaccessible or not found
```

---

Oneplus 5T, LineageOS 18.1 (Android 11)

[Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send adb command to Android 11 or 12 devices, the syntax of controlling volume has changed:

```
adb shell cmd media_session volume --set 10
```

**This is used to set the volume at `10`** — just replace `10` with your desired value.

Comment: The index range appears to be between `0` and `25`: `Error: invalid volume index 60 for stream 3 (should be in [0..25])`

Comment: output for `$ cmd media_session volume --set 10`: `[V] will set volume to index=10` \ `[V] Connecting to AudioService`

Answer (score 9):

In Android 11 and Android 12, `media` utility no longer exists. That's why you got the error since your shell could not find the utility in locations  mentioned in its PATH. That utility's commands have been moved to a service name `MediaSessionService`. To access those commands invoke this service using `cmd` command.

```
adb shell cmd media_session
```

Example:

```
$ cmd media_session                                                                                                                           
usage: media_session [subcommand] [options]
       media_session dispatch KEY
       media_session dispatch KEY
       media_session list-sessions
       media_session monitor 
       media_session volume [options]

media_session dispatch: dispatch a media key to the system.
                KEY may be: play, pause, play-pause, mute, headsethook,
                stop, next, previous, rewind, record, fast-forword.
media_session list-sessions: print a list of the current sessions.
media_session monitor: monitor updates to the specified session.
                       Use the tag from list-sessions.
media_session volume:  the options are as follows: 
                --stream STREAM selects the stream to control, see AudioManager.STREAM_*
                                controls AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC if no stream is specified
                --set INDEX     sets the volume index value
                --adj DIRECTION adjusts the volume, use raise|same|lower for the direction
                --get           outputs the current volume
                --show          shows the UI during the volume change
        examples:
                adb shell media volume --show --stream 3 --set 11
                adb shell media volume --stream 0 --adj lower
                adb shell media volume --stream 3 --get
```

The *examples* section above has not been updated in the source code to reflect new changes, that's why it still recommends using `media` or `adb shell media`.

Comment: I still get the error when running `media_session list-sessions`: `/system/bin/sh: media_session: inaccessible or not found`. `cmd media_session` outputs the same info as in your answer body. Hopefully I didn't make any obvious mistake, I'll look more into this tomorrow

Comment: You have to use cmd before media_session. cmd utility is used to call shell commands offered by system services.